# How many String objects are created in Java?

Tags: java, string, performance

I have the following Java code:

```
String a = "Java" + "Virtual" + "Machine";
```

For someone 5 objects are created.("Java", "Virtual", "Machine", "Java Virtual", "Java Virtual Machine").

But I know that this code equals that:

```
String a = new StringBuilder("Java").append("Virtual").append("Machine").toString();
```

There isn't one object here?

How many String object are created?

edit:

Same question for following code:

```
String a = "Java";
String b = "Virtual";
String c = a + b + "Machine";
```

How many String object are created?

Comment: String is immutable while StringBuilder isn't. Appending to a String(using +) always returns a new String while appending to a StringBuilder(using the append method) it returns a reference to itself, no new object is created.

Comment: maybe it got lost, but I added an answer for the second part of your question..

Comment: Your assumption that it is the same as using `StringBuilder` is false.

Comment: Your sentences starting 'for someone' and 'but I know' are both incorrect. Only one String is created in the case of constant string-literal expressions. Note that this is not an 'optimization', it is a feature of the language. @anna You are mistaken in the case of constant expressions.

Comment: @EJP thank you for your comment. Here is another useful example: `String var = "c"; String result = "a" + "b" + var + "d" + "e";` This will be optimized to: `"ab" + var + "d" + "e" `. If `var` was a "static final" variable the compiler would have optimized it like this: `abcde`  (compile-time constants).

Comment: @anna I don't know why you're addressing your new example to me. It's the OP who is asking the question. But you're mistaken again. `static` has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

There is exact 1 string object created, the compiler optimalizes `String a = "Java" + "Virtual" + "Machine";` to `String a = "JavaVirtualMachine";`.

This can be seem with the output of `javap -c Test`, I used a `System.out.println` to prevent the compiler from optimizing it fully away:

```
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test {
  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // String JavaVirtualMachine
       2: astore_1
       3: getstatic     #3                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       6: aload_1
       7: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      10: return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will optimize the code to equal this:

```
String a = "JavaVirtualMachine";
```

The more interesting question is probably what this does:

```
int x = 5;
String a = "foo" + x + "bar";
```

In which case the compiler will create a `StringBuilder` and append all values.
This would roughly translate to this code:

```
int x = 5;
String a = new StringBuilder().append("foo").append(x).append("bar").toString();
```

But if you are concatenating `String`s in a loop, the compiler will create a `StringBuilder` in each iteration. So if you have a code like this:

```
String[] errorMessages = getErrorMessages();
String output = "Found the following error messages:";
for(int i = 0; i < errorMessages.length(); i++){
    output += "\n" + (i+1) + ": " + errorMessages[i];
}
```

This would translate (again roughly) to:

```
String[] errorMessages = getErrorMessages();
String output = "Found the following error messages:";
for(int i = 0; i < errorMessages.length(); 
    output = new StringBuilder(output).append('\n')
            .append((i+1)).append(": ").append(errorMessages[i]).toString();
}
```

Like mentioned, this creates a new `StringBuilder` in each iteration. So in these cases it is better not to rely on the compiler to do it's magic, create your own `StringBuilder`, and use the same object throughout the whole iteration:

```
String[] errorMessages = getErrorMessages();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Found the following error messages:");
for(int i = 0; i < errorMessages.length(); i++){
    builder.append('\n').append((i+1)).append(": ").append(errorMessages[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why can't the compiler use a StringBuilder in a loop? and what does it do instead?

Comment: ok, that way of putting it may be a bit confusing. I'll update the text to be a bit more obvious what I meant

Comment: There you go, this should leave no doubt as to what I meant :)

Comment: The statement I asked about remains. You should fix it.

Comment: It can use a `StringBuilder` in a loop and I already posted what it does instead. I rephrased the first bit to make it less confusing, if that is what you were referring to..